# \setlength{\belowcaptionskip} is not the same as \vspace

Tags: spacing, captions, baseline, vspace

Following [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/628116/180429), I noticed that adding

```
\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
```

right after the graphics insertion, does not gives the same exact result when comparing the output with

```
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-0.5\baselineskip}
```

in the document preamble.

In the image you can see the two pages of the two outputs shown side by side, with green lines as a visual aid.

[image: 2 pages]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-0.5\baselineskip}   <<-- With or without

\begin{document}
The universe is immense and it seems to be homogeneous, 
in a large scale, everywhere we look at.
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{./orange.png}
\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}                         <<-- With or without
\caption{Color orange is not a real color}
\end{figure}

There's a picture of a galaxy above.


\end{document}
```

Can anyone give a little insight to why there is a difference?

Comment: in one you are adding space above the caption and the other you are adding it below the caption

Comment: did you mean to compare with `\vspace` placed below the caption?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes. My goal is to omit the `\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip} ` command every time I insert a graphics inside a figure. So I thought that adding the `setlength{}{}` to the preamble would give the same effect. Am I wrong?

Comment: but `\belowcaptionskip` is a space added below the caption and you are comparing it with a vspace added above the caption so a completely differrent place. (also it is only coincidental that 0.5\baselineskip has the same value in the preamble and after the caption)

Comment: abovecaptionskip is 10pt and you are explicitly backspacing by half baselineskip so 6pt so what you seem to want to do is set \abovecaptionskip to 4pt leaving belowcaptionskip as 0pt, but I am just guessing your intent here

Comment: Well it seems (after a check), that I need to change from `\belowcaptionskip`, as I wrote in the original question, to `\abovecaptionskip{0.5\baselineskip}`. Still there a few pixels difference between that and using the `\vspace`.

Comment: well yes of course: if you use the default of 10pt and backspace by 6pt then that is 4pt space but if you set it to 6pt and don't backspace then that is 2pt difference

Comment: it is much clearer to use explicit units rather than multiples of \baselineskip as you are relying on \baselineskip having specific values at the point you use `\setlength` which may be unrelated to the value of `\baselineskip` at the point the caption skip is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In article class `\abovecaptionskip` is 10pt and `\belowcaptionskip`is 0pt and `\baselineskip` is 12pt, so your construct

```
\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}                         <<-- With or without
\caption{Color orange is not a real color}
```

is effectively setting 4pt above and 0pt below the caption so equivalent to omitting the `\vspace` and setting

```
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{4pt}
```